# How to detect if a function inside a constructor was called as an constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

So I have created this function that checks if it was called as a constructor:

```
{
    this.x = function() {
        if (!this instanceof x) {
            return new x;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

but now I want to have a function inside that should also be called as an constructor

```
{
    this.x = function() {
        if (!this instanceof x) {
            return new x;
        }
        this.y = function(){
            if (!this instanceof y) {
                return new y;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

However, when I try to do this, I get a TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

How can I check if the function `y` was called as an constructor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Um... where is `y` even defined?

Comment: By the way, your `if` statement is actually `if ( (!this) instanceof x)`. Logical NOT `!` (16) has higher precedence than `instanceof` (11): [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Comment: You've set *y* as a property of *this*, not a local variable, so you can't access it as a local variable. You could try an arrow function and `this.y` instead. If the first case works, *x* must be a global variable.